# How compare part of a date in Doctrine2

Tags: php, date, doctrine-orm

How can I extract part of the date (e.g. the month) in DQL?

I'm trying to use a query something like this:

```
$query = $qb->select('u')
->from('user', 'u')
->where('MONTH(u.birthdate)', $month)
->getQuery();
```

I'm trying to select all users who's birthday is in the current month. Is this possible? how?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
->where('MONTH(u.birthdate)=:month')->setParameter("month", $month)
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable those MySQL function like MONTH, YEAR, etc, you will have to first install them and enable them, you can get it here from Benjamin Eberlei [Doctrine 2 Extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions.git)

and follow the instrucions.